# How to Hot Reload shared library on Linux

Tags: c++, c, dll, shared-libraries, elf

I'm attempting to replicate a cool trick out of Casey Muratori's popular [Handmade Hero series](https://youtu.be/oijEnriqqcs).  On win32, Casey was able to reload a DLL and see his code changes with only a few milliseconds of latency.

I'm trying to replicate this behavior on linux using dlopen, dlsym, dlclose and stat, but I'm running into the below behavior, and I have a hunch that I'm either misunderstanding something about ELF, the example, the linker, or perhaps the concept of shared objects all together.

I was able to get his code working without much difficult on win32, so I feel this is something specific to Linux that I'm missing.

I am using CMake to build, but I don't particularly believe CMake is the culprit.

I make a copy of the shared library dynamic.so, and load that.  Whenever the mtime of the original shared object updates, I close out the handle to the old copy, make a new copy, and then try to load the new copy.

I would like to point out that it was my intention to break the loop after the first change, since I'm just trying to figure this out.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <dlfcn.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <time.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#include <sys/stat.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#include <unistd.h>      

void
CopyFile(const char* src, const char* dest)
{
  FILE* fsrc;
  FILE* fdest;
  unsigned char buffer[512];
  size_t bytes;

  fprintf(stderr, "copy from: %s to %s!\n", src, dest);

  fsrc = fopen(src, "rb");
  if ( fsrc == NULL )
    ┆   fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file: %s for reading\n", src);

  fdest = fopen(dest, "wb");
  if ( fdest == NULL )
    ┆   fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file: %s for reading\n", src);

  while ( (bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fsrc)) > 0 )
    {
    ┆   fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, fdest);
    }

  fclose(fsrc);
  fclose(fdest);

  fprintf(stderr, "copy complete!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

const char* libpath = "/home/bacon/dynamic.so";
const char* copypath = "/home/bacon/dynamic-copy.so";
CopyFile(libpath, copypath);

void* handle = dlopen(copypath, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if ( handle == NULL )
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to load %s, error = %s\n", copypath, dlerror());

struct stat s;
stat(libpath, &s);
time_t oldtime = s.st_mtime;
while (true)
{
    stat(libpath, &s);
    if ( oldtime != s.st_mtime )
    {
        if ( handle != NULL )
        {
            if ( dlclose(handle) )
                fprintf(stderr, "dlclose failed: %s\n", dlerror());
            else
                handle = NULL;
        }

        CopyFile(libpath, copypath);

        handle = dlopen(copypath, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
        if ( handle == NULL )
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to load %s, error = %s\n", copypath, dlerror());

        break;
    }
}
}
```

As for the Dynamic Library, anything should do (example header):

```cpp
#ifndef DYNAMIC_HEADER
#define DYNAMIC_HEADER 1

#define DYNAMIC_API __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))

extern "C" DYNAMIC_API int
Add(int x, int y);

#endif /* DYNAMIC_HEADER */
```

And the source file:

```cpp
#include "Dynamic.h"

int
Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

The shared library simply provides a few routines to add a few numbers together, and I've validated that I was able to dlopen and dlsym without the hot reload trickery.

I also validated my copy routine actually copies the shared object.

I expected the initial dlopen to succeed, and dlsym to correctly link Add (which it would).  I would then edit Dynamic.cpp and perhaps return x + x + y or something, save the file and recompile, expecting the while loop to pick up the change in st_mtime.

I noticed that when I ran the code and updated I received the error:

```sh
dlopen: file too short
```

Sure enough, when I ls -la the directory containing the shared objects, the copy was size 0.

Somehow, the st_mtime reported by stat is updated, but the actual contents of the shared object are empty?  Is the linker locking up the shared object and preventing reads?

If my code isn't horribly wrong, how can I circumvent this sort of behavior?

I'm disinclined to sleep and retry, as this was intended to be a rather instantaneous update.

Comment: What is CopyFile? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Sounds like a race-condition. Instead of 'simple copy' create temporary files and rename them to the final name (rename is an atomic operation). Do this in both of your programs.

Comment: Updated to include my implementation of CopyFile, using fopen and friends.  I forgot this wasn't win32.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond so CMake builds a temporary library file, and as a post build action renames to the proper location?

Comment: It's not about cmake; do something like this `cd builddir; make libdynamic.so; cp libdynamic.so targetpath/libdynamic.willbeso; mv -f targetpath/libdynamic.willbeso targetpath/libdynamic.so` this will replace the shared object in one atomic step

Comment: Take a look here for a full sample: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-018/

Answer (score 3):

> If my code isn't horribly wrong

It is horribly wrong: your code is racing with the (static) linker (invoked by `make` or `cmake`).

When `make` runs, it (eventually) invokes:

```
gcc -shared -o /home/bacon/dynamic.so foo.o bar.o ...
```

The linker will then perform `open("/home/bacon/dynamic.so", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, ...)` (or equivalent), and some time later will `write` and finally `close` the file.

Your program will wake up when `m_time` has changed, which is *any* time after `open`, and will attempt to copy the file. IF your copy happens at any time *before* the final `close`, then you could end up with a partial copy (including a partial copy that contains 0 bytes).

The most obvious solution is the one suggested by Zsigmond: you must modify the `Makefile` to link a *different* file from the one you are watching, and perform a `mv` to final destination as the last (atomic) step.

An alternative solution is to have a `make` target that depends on `dynamic.so`, e.g.

```
dynamic.so.done: dynamic.so
        touch dynamic.so.done
```

In your program, you would watch `m_time` for the `dynamic.so.done`, and only when *that* file is updated, perform the copy of `dynamic.so` (which is guaranteed to have been `close`d by that point).

Comment: Excellent, this also confirms and lines up with my other reading.  Writes by the linker are not all done at once.  I believe my personal best solution will be touching a file after the build completes.  Thank you.